# Samba config options allowed in usershare

Tags: samba

I've added a usershare on Ubuntu 20.04, and can connect/read/write just fine from my Windows 10 machine. However, I wanted to be able to execute some .bat files on the mounted drive. I know I can explicitly set the execute bit on those files but since there are lots of them I wanted to try using the `acl allow execute always` option on that share.

When I've added it to the usershare config file manually, I'm unable to execute. If I instead add it to the global section of smb.conf it works as expected. Furthermore, if I run `net usershare info <share-name>` it only displays the automatically created config entries, not the ones I added manually.

What config entries can be added to a usershare config file and respected by Samba? For any config options that won't be used from the usershare file, can I add a share section by the same name in smb.conf to add those additional options?

Answer (score 0):

Usershares are controlled by smb.conf and all of the parameters available to smb.conf will work on all usershares but only at the [global] level - not at the share level. So they will influence all shares.

If you have specific share level requirements to a given share it would be best to create your shares in smb.conf directly and not use usershares.

What you do not want to do is create a samba share using both "classic" shares ( smb.conf ) and usershares -- at the same time -- on the same folder -- with the same share name. Samba will get confused as to which one should be obeyed.